# Default sorting as descending on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable

I am using the below jQuery to sort(descending) table on page load. It is working only after I click the arrows for descending or ascending.But,my requirement was to sort the table descending on page load.Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
oTable = $('#personsList').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "iDisplayLength": 25,
                    "aLengthMenu": [25, 50, 100, 150],
                    "aaSorting": [],                    
                    "bPaginate": false              
                });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use that `aaSorting` parameter to initialize sorting on a specific column.

Below code sorts 1st column asc.

```
           $(document).ready(function() { 
                 oTable = $('#personsList').dataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 25,
                "aLengthMenu": [25, 50, 100, 150],
                "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']],      //Sorts 1st column asc              
                "bPaginate": false              
            });
```

[Complete datatables params reference](http://datatables.net/ref)

Comment: @user1078081 Then use "aaSorting": [[0,'asc']]

Comment: I used "aaSorting": [[0,'desc']] and is sorting descending on page load which is required.Thank you!

Comment: may be worth updating the comment "//Sorts 3rd column asc" since you changed it to [0,'asc']? just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

By this code you can sort individual columns on datatables by adding class 'sort-desc' or 'sort-asc' for sorting ascending and descending on page load

```
    $('.dom-table').each(function(index) {
        var sort_column=$('.dom-table thead tr').children().index('.sort-desc');
        var sort_oper='desc';
        if(sort_column < 0)
        {
            var sort_column=$('.dom-table thead tr').children().index('.sort-asc');
            sort_oper='asc';
            if(sort_column < 0)
            {
                sort_column=0;
            }
        }
        $(this).dataTable({
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "aaSorting": [[sort_column,sort_oper]],
    });
});
```

I have not tested this code but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **order** property to achieve the same.

For example in the following Table it will be sorted in **descending** order by *4th Column (index starts from ZERO!)*

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({

            "order": [
                      [3, 'desc']      
                     ]
        });
```

Checkout [this Fiddle](http://live.datatables.net/wotoqequ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

What method is being called, when you click the sorting-arrows? Why don't you call just this method as the last method-call in the document.ready function?